# Exception while connecting AWS server for MQTT

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-sdk

I have tried to run example from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/AndroidPubSub/README.md. I have changed `PoolId`, `End Server` and `Policy Name`. I am getting following exception.

`Exception occurred when generating new private key and certificate.                                                                                                                   com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'us-west-2_something' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+ (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: f7c3924a-e847-11e6-8508-ab41b4890740)`

Comment: One problem, one question, do not substantially change questions once they have been answered as it makes them useless to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the Cognito [console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/federated?region=us-east-1) and create a Cognito Identity Pool and replace `us-west-2_something` with the actual identity pool id that looks like this `us-west-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`